# Using angular-ui-select in the kendo ui grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, angular-ui-select

I am building an angular app and I am using the kendo ui grid in inline edit mode.

I have been looking for an example using the [angular-ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki) in the kendo grid. But I only found an example using the [kendoDropDownList with jquery](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom)

An example using the kendoDropDownList or angular-ui-select in an angular controller would bee much appreciated.